# Strange CSS behavior on dual display setup

Tags: css, sass

It's hard for me to point to the exact issue, but the problem is following:

CSS works fine with any setup I've tested (mobile, different resolutions [inc. maximize and manual resize], screen color depth, etc)

The problem starts when I maximize the page **only** when I have multiple monitors connected. This not happen, for example when I have laptop and monitor setup. Only two connected monitors.

Now, it's enough to make it a bit less (resize manual) everything returns to the perfect order. But maximization (as well as splitting the page between two monitors) causes problem.

The thing is that it is not clear what the problem is. All css rendered correctly, no canceled css, nothing. It just brakes.

Any ideas?

Here the [live URL](https://telesa.support) for test (system is alive)

**UPDATE** The reason was strange behavior of media query max width and min width. For some reason, it is not being detected correctly with multiple screens on large resolutions >3500.
Issue is fixed by increasing max-width to 10K

Comment: Does the problem happen on any browser? You are not being clear on what's the problem (you just say there's a problem and the css "breaks" and posted a link to your site), add a picture, something, and check the guidelines to add an minimal example to reproduce the problem, it's hard to tell inspecting a whole site.

Comment: @arieljuod you are correct. This is Chrome. Here the screenshots https://imgur.com/a/VPNL3r7 as you can see the only different is maximize on dual monitor. resolution is the same. The same issue also happen if i split it (in any size) between monitors

Comment: Did you try with Firefox/Edge/Safari? maybe you don't have a CSS problem but something on Chrome is messing things up. I don't have two monitors to try it though, check if this is a crossbrowser issue or just chrome. Also, try to add a minimal example to reproduce the problem (or at leeeeast the related html and css code). Check SO guidelines to ask questions.

Comment: The problem is the same for Firefox and Safari. I would love to build small reproducible sample, if I would know at least the direction of the problem. But I am clueless at this time... This is all looks very very strange

Answer (score 0):

The reason was strange behavior of media query `max-width` and `min-width`. For some reason, it is not being detected correctly with multiple screens on large resolutions >3500. Issue is fixed by increasing `max-width` to 10K

Comment: Indeed strange. Seems like css sum the monitors viewport as one screen??